# MapActivity in TabHost

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, parent-child, android-tabhost

I have a CUSTOM tab host the uses the addTab() method instead of tabspec. one of my tabs in a MapViewthat shows a specific location. The problem I am encountering is an exception on the line in my tabhost that sets up the mapview tab.

Tab Activity (removed package for confidential reasons):

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class CustomTabHost extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabhost);
    setTabs() ;
}
private void setTabs()
{
    addTab("Services", R.drawable.servicesicon, services.class);
    addTab("Our Work", R.drawable.ourworkicon, ourwork.class);

    addTab("RSS", R.drawable.rssicon, RSSReader.class);
    addTab("Locate IML", R.drawable.locateicon, Locate.class);
    addTab("Contact IML", R.drawable.contacticon, ContactUs.class);
}

private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
{
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title1);
    title.setText(labelId);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon1);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}

}
```

MapActivity:

```
import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class Locate extends MapActivity  { 


   @Override 
   protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
           super.onCreate(icicle); 
            setContentView(R.layout.locateiml); 


 MapView mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.locatemap);
 mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

  List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapview.getOverlays();
  Drawable drawable =this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.locateicon);
  Locateoverlay itemoverlay = new Locateoverlay(drawable, this);
  GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(382571066,-85751392);
  OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Interactive", null);

 itemoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

 mapOverlays.add(itemoverlay);
}
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
 {
return false;
}
 }
```

There is also an overlay, but that is not needed for this question. My question is, I am pretty sure I need to create a parent activity the handles the map activity, but I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the Activity in TabHost is not considered as Activity. I think it is managed as View.
In my case, main Activity was inherited Activity and TabHost was implemented through xml configuration. Then I added MapActivity -as a TabSpec- to TabHost, but MapView shows gray background only.
So, I make main Activity inherit MapActivity, and it worked.
I don't know whether this is best solution, whether your main Activity must inherit TabActivity, but if there is no obvious reason, I think it is better to inherit MapActivity rather then TabActivity.
Maybe my answer is not the best, I wish I could help you in some way.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`TabActivity` caused me a lot of issues in the past. This might be another issue related to it.

Right now `TabActivity` is deprecated. The doc says:

> New applications should use Fragments instead of this class; to
>   continue to run on older devices, you can use the v4 support library
>   which provides a version of the Fragment API that is compatible down
>   to DONUT.

To use a `MapView` inside a `Fragment` you will need to use: petedoyle's [android-support-v4-googlemaps](https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps).